# Magento 1.9 add category root in grid column

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I have already a column with category that I call from database. for exemple I have **Women** as main category and then their subcategory **Tops & blouses** and **Pants & Denim** .
So what I need to implement is like **Women->Pants & Denim** in a column grid.I've tried with a foreach but I can't display results in the column.

this is my Grid.php

```
class Ns_Thorleif_Block_Adminhtml_Commerciaux_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('commerciaux_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id'); // Order by entity_id ASC
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    public function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $subcategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            //->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array(2, 37))
            ->setOrder('parent_id', 'ASC');//if you want them somehow grouped by parent_id

        $categories = array();
        foreach ($subcategories as $category) {
            //do something with $category
            if ($category['level'] > 1) {
                $categories[$category['entity_id']] = array($category['entity_id'], 'name' => $category['name'],'route' => $category['level']);
            }
            var_dump($categories);
        }

        $collection = Mage::getModel('thorleif/commerciaux')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array("nin" => array(1,2))); //Where entity_id not in (1,2)
        foreach ($collection as $row) {
            $retour .= $row->name.'<br />'; 
        }

        //return $retour;
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    public function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('entity_id',
            array(
                'header' => 'ID',
                'align' => 'left',
                'width' => '10%',
                'index' => 'entity_id'
            )
        );
        $this->addColumn('name',
            array(
                'header' => 'Category Name',
                'align' => 'left',
                'index' => 'name'
            )
        );
        $this->addColumn('route',
            array(
                'header' => 'Route',
                'align' => 'left',
                'index' => $category['name']
            )
        );
        $this->addColumn('linio',
            array(
                'header' => 'Linio Category',
                'align' => 'left',
                'index' => 'linio'
            )
        );
        $this->addColumn('tax',
            array(
                'header' => 'Tax',
                'align' => 'left',
                'index' => 'tax'
            )
        );
        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header' => 'Action',
                'align' => 'left',
                'index' => 'action'
            )
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

my grid look like this

[image]

and There is a way to put the grid into a form with form header title?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more information as I am not able to determine the issue here. Put grid into a form??

Comment: For the Form, I've added an image to see what I'm talking about. For the grid, in the first column I have the shop categories and in the second column I want to put the root of each category like this "maincategory->subcat1->subsubcat1"  or "maincategory->subcat2" or "maincategory->subcat3"  depending for each level, for example for the main it will be the same but for subcategories level I'd like to put it as root using ->

Comment: Can you add code for your current form file?

Comment: I have the code for the form in a file and the grid in disctinct file, so I don't know how to put the same in one page.